# childViewControllers differ in viewDidLoad and prepareForSegue

Tags: ios, swift

I have three containers in my storyboard with three different view controller classes embedded in them (A, B, C).

I want set delegates before these view controllers are embedded. I want to do this within prepareForSegue. However, I find that there is a difference between the child controllers there within viewDidLoad and prepareForSegue, why is this?

If I run for viewController in self.viewControllers in viewDidLoad, I receive back A, B, C.

If I run the same command in prepareForSegue I get A, A, B.

Where has class C gone from prepareForSegue?

Reordering the containers in the Storyboard change those viewControllers that I return back. If I place B at the top then I get back B, B, A in the prepareForSegue method.

[image: There are three containers in my storyboard]

The top is class A, the left is class B, the right is class C.

They are all embedded in a HomeViewController UIViewController Class.

In HomeViewController:

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
        for childController in self.childViewControllers {
            print("in view did load")
            print(childController)
        }

    }

   override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {

        print(segue.identifier)
         for childController in self.childViewControllers {
            print(childController)
        }
}
```

So I think this is because when the first embedSegue is called, there are no childViewControllers right, as the embed is being called before embed?

So I guess my question really is, how can I set a delegate relationship between these view controllers when they haven't yet been embedded and added to childControllers?

Comment: And we can figure this out with?

Comment: Please post some code snippets and screenshots to help us to virtualize your problem better.

Comment: @YeLiu - Sorry about that, I have added more.

Comment: @Eendje - Sorry about that, I have added more.